# jquery mobile loading bar on iphone

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have noticed that when I load the folowing code on iphone the url stays loading the page at about 10%. The page does fully load that I can see. Very little code on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page">
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="controlgroup">
                    <a href="mob_date.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Check Availability</a>
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">About Us</a>
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Gallery</a>
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Find Us</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A note perhaps. I know JQuery Mobile is HTML5 based, but your doctype is XHTML. Try <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Did think that myself alright. I have updated it by still the same issue of url bar stopping and the loading phones loading circle moving

Comment: seems to load fine: http://jsfiddle.net/5FgqL/ and http://jsfiddle.net/5FgqL/1/

Comment: Yes, thanks, I have a mod rewrite to make sure that everything is directed over ssl. So what I have done is not use the cdn and run everything from the server. It may have been some content was secure and some not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have stored all the jQuery files on my server. It seems like the iphone does not like some files coming form a secure connection an others form non secure.